# Для чего нужен editor-style.css?

Tags: css, wordpress

Как я понимаю, `editor-style.css` нужен для того, чтобы внешний вид статьи в редакторе соответствовал тому, как будет выглядеть статья на сайте.

Но ведь все нужные стили можно прописать в`style.css` и привязать его (тогда в 
`editor-style.css` нет необходимости, и не нужно создавать дополнительный файл).

Может, я что-то не так понимаю или не знаю каких-то нюансов и удобств использования `editor-style.css`?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style

Answer (score 0):

Файл editor-style.css служит для задания стилей встроенного редактора tinymce. Формально никакой связи с тем, как статья будет выглядеть на сайте, он не имеет. Да, можно подогнать стили editor-style.css под стили style.css.

Если вы создаете собственную тему, то можно обойтись и без editor-style.css.

В twentyseventeen 6 файлов css, используемых для различных особенностей сайта (например, для написания справа налево). Объединять все их в один файл - неразумно, потому что это затруднит поддержку темы. Думаю, что разработчики темы руководствовались именно этими соображениями.

Comment: Вы пишете: «можно подогнать стили editor-style.css под стили style.css». То есть, можно и не делать этого? Но разве назначение editor-style.css не в том, чтобы в редакторе сразу было видно, как статья будет выглядеть на сайте? И зачем подгонять, если можно назначить одинаковые правила?

Comment: tinymce может вообще не использоваться (первая опция в /wp-admin/profile.php). Будет лишний код в style.css. И что вы выиграете от того, что будет не 6 файлов css, а 5?